# Prefix automatically created roles using AWS CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cdk

I need to be able to prefix any roles that are automatically created when deploying a stack and I am having trouble finding where and how to do this?

So when the iam:CreateRole is called on something like `arn:aws:iam::***:role/cdk-hnb659fds-cfn-exec-role-***-region` I would like it to be `arn:aws:iam::***:role/{$customPrefix}-cdk-hnb659fds-cfn-exec-role-***-region`.

I tried to override the `allocateLogicalId` in my stack:

```
 public allocateLogicalId(element: CfnElement) {
    const orig = super.allocateLogicalId(element);
    const prefix = "custom-";
    return prefix ? prefix + orig : orig;
  }
```

But if I want to add a `-` it complains about `Error: Resolution error: Resolution error: Resolution error: Resolution error: Logical ID must adhere to the regular expression: /^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]{1,254}$/, got 'custom-AppSyncAPIApiB9F19C81'.`.

if I don't add a dash it works. But it also prefixes everything in my stack. I would like to only prefix the IAM roles that are being created.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

`cdk bootstrap` [deploys a CloudFormation template](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/master/packages/aws-cdk/lib/api/bootstrap/bootstrap-template.yaml). The template defines the bootstrapping roles' Physical IDs (= names) using substitution patterns:

```yaml
# bootstrap-template.yaml
RoleName:
  Fn::Sub: cdk-${Qualifier}-file-publishing-role-${AWS::AccountId}-${AWS::Region}
```

Bootstrap the environment with a custom template, in which you modify the role names:

```sh
# print the default template to the console
cdk bootstrap --show-template

# bootstrap with a custom template
cdk bootstrap --template my-bootstrap-template.yaml
```